# CodeIgniter - Como fazer um select na consulta do banco?

Tags: php, mysql, html5, codeigniter

Estou fazendo uma aplicação de lista de pacientes para cirurgia e  utilizando o `CodeIgniter` e `Bootstrap`. Minha duvida é como fazer um select na consulta do banco para que ele me mostre na tabela apenas os resultados que não possuem o `status_paciente = "realizado"`

Não estou usando a model para fazer a consulta por enquanto, adicionei no próprio `controler`. A tabela em uso é a "pacientes" e o paciente que eu não quero mostrar no select é o que tem o "status_paciente" com valor = "realizado".

Meu `Controler`:

```
public function index()
{

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->join('medico','id_medico=idMedico','inner');
        $dados['paciente'] = $this->db->get('paciente')->result();
        $this->load->view('includes/html_header');
        $this->load->view('includes/menu');
        $this->load->view('listar_paciente', $dados);
        $this->load->view('includes/html_footer');
}
```

Minha View:(apenas a parte onde esta a tabela que mostra os dados da consulta)

```
<h4>Lista de Pacientes</h4>
      <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped table-sm" id="myTable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
                <th hidden>ID</th>
              <th>Ordem</th>
              <th style="width:100px">Data</th>
              <th>Prontuario</th>
              <th>Nome</th>
              <th>Sexo</th>
              <th>Procedimento</th>
              <th>OPME</th>
              <th>Observações</th>
              <th>LAB</th>
              <th>Risco</th>
              <th>Raio X</th>
              <th>Outros</th>
              <th>Médico</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <?php foreach($paciente as $pac){?>
            <tr>
              <td hidden><?= $pac->id; ?></td>
                <td><?= $pac->ordem; ?></td>
              <td><?= date('d/m/y',strtotime($pac->data)); ?></td>
              <td><?= $pac->prontuario; ?></td>
              <td><?= $pac->nome; ?></td>
              <td><?= $pac->sexo=='m'?'Masculino':'Feminino'; ?></td>
              <td><?= $pac->procedimento; ?></td>
              <td><?= $pac->opme; ?></td>
              <td><?= $pac->observacoes; ?></td>
              <td><?= $pac->lab; ?></td>
              <td><?= $pac->risco; ?></td>
              <td><?= $pac->raiox; ?></td>
              <td><?= $pac->outros; ?></td>
                <td><?= $pac->abreviacao; ?></td>
                <td><?= $pac->status_paciente; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="<?= base_url('nir/alterar/'. $pac->id)?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-group">Atualizar</a></td>
                    <td><a href="<?= base_url('nir/excluir/'. $pac->id)?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-group" onclick="return confirm('Deseja Realmente Remover Este Paciente?')">Remover</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php }?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá tudo bem? Para seu exemplo especificado acima, você pode fazer:

`$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->join('medico','id_medico=idMedico','inner');
$this->db->where_not_in('status_paciente', 'realizado');
$dados['paciente'] = $this->db->get('paciente')->result();`

Seguindo a documentação do [Codeigniter](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/index.html), para fazer um [SELECT](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data) através da classe [Query Builder](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html)(classe para manipulação de consultas banco de dados), é:

- Todos os registros de uma tabela:

`$query = $this->db->get('mytable');`

- Você pode inserir o código select em SQL também (que no seu caso pode dar um WHERE status_paciente NOT IN ('realizado') :

`$this->db->select('(SELECT SUM(payments.amount) FROM payments WHERE payments.invoice_id=4) AS amount_paid', FALSE);
$query = $this->db->get('mytable')`

- Utilizando [WHERE](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)

`$this->db->where('status_paciente != "realizado");` ou

`$this->db->where('status_paciente !=', $status_realizado);` ou ainda melhor:

`$this->db->where_not_in('status_paciente', 'realizado');`

Consulte [aqui](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html) a documentação para saber mais informações.
(o exemplo acima segue a documentação da versão mais atual do CodeIgniter, caso seja diferente da que usa, consulta a de mesma versão).

Espero ter contribuído!

Comment: Deu certo, Obrigado, vou dar uma olhada na documentação para fazer tudo correto

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seja apenas fazer o select da maneira que você deseja, tenho um exemplo em que faço uma consulta ao banco, vou passar aqui vê se te ajuda

```
$sql = "select login, senha from data where login ='$login' and senha ='$senha'";
```

Comment: não consegui fazer dessa forma, mas obrigado pela resposta, segui a dica do Luiz Fernando